# Link to start Instagram chat

Tags: instagram

Is there a way to start an Instagram direct conversation with a link (just like there is https://wa.me/text to start a whats app conversation)? Or what can I do to do something similar?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

No. Instagram [documents their available URL schemes](https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/), and initiating a direct message is not one of the available options at this time. Your best bet will be linking to their user profile; it should only be a click away to initiate a conversation.

```
<a href="instagram://user?username=USERNAME">
```

Answer (score 0):

Good news Guys !!

I have found a solution to directly open an Instagram Chat using ADB/Shell command.

So all you need to do is first fire up logcat and click on a notification which has a message for you and check your logcat to find the DATA_URI like the following:

*`START u0 {dat=ig://direct_v2?id=XXXXXXXX&x=XXXXXXXXXXX&push_category=null&user_id=XXXXXX&calling_package=com.instagram.android&entry_point=push flg=0x4000000 pkg=com.instagram.android cmp=com.instagram.android/com.instagram.mainactivity.MainActivity (has extras)} from uid 10071`*

and then note the following parameters:

1. id (This is the recipient id that will be used to select the contact)
2. user_id [optional](this is the id that is used to mention which account to use)

and then construct the am command as such:

Note: Use --user parameter only when you are using termux and user_id parameter is optional.

```
For Termux:
$am start -f 0x4000000 -n com.instagram.android/com.instagram.mainactivity.MainActivity --user 10071 -d "ig://direct_v2?id=XXXXXXXX&push_category=null&user_id=XXXXXXXX&calling_package=com.instagram.android&entry_point=push"

For ADB Shell:
$am start -f 0x4000000 -n com.instagram.android/com.instagram.mainactivity.MainActivity -d "ig://direct_v2?id=XXXXXXXX&x=XXXXXXXXXXX&push_category=null&user_id=XXXXXXXX&calling_package=com.instagram.android&entry_point=push"
```

From what I think, this method is efficient as you might wanna note that the id parameter is obtained by Just opening instagram on a browser and open the chat to specific contact and grab the value after "https://www.instagram.com/direct/t/". And the second thing I noticed is that the user_id parameter is what defines our account's id.
Give this method a shot and let me know if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can start a chat using the following link: `https://ig.me/m/username`